# Google Calendar API v3: how to get a list of resources

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to see if it is possible to get a list of resources in the primary calendar.
Looking at the Calendar API v3 I do not see how to get such a list.

I know it is possible since there is a script "Calendar Resource Meter: usage analysis", which somehow does what I want... but there is no source code available in python that i can look at (and get inspiration)

Any help appreciated

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but I suspect that a Resource is simply a special type of Event. Try using the event api described here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it and look at the results.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a list of resources at your organisation from the Google Calendar API.  To get a list of resources you need to use the [Google Apps Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/).